# How can I compress PNM file to JPEG with custom quantization table with ImageMagick

Tags: c++, imagemagick

How can I compress PNM file to JPEG with custom  quantization table with ImageMagick

Can I do that with C++ programming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What a coincidence: http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=20414

Woops that probably is you ?